# How to change the address format shown on the user account dashboard?

Tags: magento-1.7, customer-address

I'm trying to make changes on the user addresses format but I didn't get it yet. I've tried to change the format directly on /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml but without success. Basically what I need is two changes: first, show the second address line besides first line, because I'm using the first only for the street name and the second only for number. However, for a layout questions, I don't want an entire line just to show a number, so, I wanna put the number besides the street name (in Brazil we use the format Street Name, comma, number, comma, ap/suite etc.). How to?

The second detail is: how to show in admin area, on the customer management page, a custom field I've used in registration page, like "How did you find us?", for example.

Thanks!!

Comment: So what line are you using for apartment/suite/etc? Be very careful with translation hacks like these. The data is no longer what it is expected to be, by both Magento and extensions.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it what are you asking for but Magento keeps address templates at `Admin \ Customer \ Customer Configuration \ Address Templates`.

Comment: Greaaaat! I didn't view that option to edit inside admin directly. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Find address format module here you can define Address format base on customer country.

https://github.com/kandarp26/magento_Addressformat-1.0.1